# How to ensure to find all solutions of a trigonometric equation?

Tags: trigonometry, angle

[image: Problem]

Hi, so I was doing this question and I found the solution $\theta = \frac{5}{12}\pi$ equating $\theta+\frac{\pi}6$ to $\pi-\theta$.
However, there is also another solution for this equation $\frac{11}{12}\pi$, I don't understand how am I suppose to ensure that all solutions in a given range have been found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have:
$$\tan(\pi-\theta)=\tan\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$$
What you did is from this, conclude that $\pi-\theta=\theta+\frac{\pi}{6}$. However, this is false. The following is true:
$$(\pi-\theta)-\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\pi n \text{ for some } n \in \Bbb{Z}$$
Now, we need to solve for $\theta$ in terms of $n$ to get all of the solutions. Simplify the left side:
$$-2\theta+\frac{5\pi}{6}=\pi n \text{ for some } n \in \Bbb{Z}$$
Solve for $\theta$:
$$\theta=\frac{5\pi}{12}-\frac{\pi}{2} n \text{ for some } n \in \Bbb{Z}$$
Now, here are some of the solutions:
$$n=1 \implies \theta=-\frac{\pi}{12}$$
$$n=0 \implies \theta=\frac{5\pi}{12}$$
$$n=-1 \implies \theta=\frac{11\pi}{12}$$
$$n=-2 \implies \theta=\frac{17\pi}{12}$$
If we are talking about the range of $\theta \in [0, \pi]$, $n=0$ and $n=-1$ are the only solutions since $n=1$ and $n=-2$ are outside of this range. However, for $\theta \in \Bbb{R}$, there are an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: One of your 1's is missing a negative sign

Comment: Alright, that is fine. My question would be: how to know when to apply that rule? Is it always the case?

Comment: @Triatticus I think I fixed the typo you were talking about. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @daljit97 Whenever you have $\tan x=\tan y$ or $\cot x=\cot y$, you apply this rule. The rule for $\sin x=\sin y$ or $\csc x=\csc y$ is $$x-y=2\pi n \text{ OR } x+y=\pi+2\pi n \text{ for some } n \in \Bbb{Z}$$ The rule for $\cos x=\cos y$ or $\sec x=\sec y$ is: $$x-y=2\pi n \text{ OR } x+y=2\pi n \text{ for some } n \in \Bbb{Z}$$

Comment: @NobleMushtak do you know what are the name of those rules or where there are derived from?

Comment: @daljit97 These rules come from the unit circle and thinking about what types of angles have the same $\sin$ or the same $\cos$. I don't think they have a name, though.